Why do my ffmpeg hevc_amf options have no Effect
I'm starting to get into videoengineering. I was trying to compare the different hardware encoders in my devices. I want to encode a vp9 video to hevc. Therefore I'm using FFmpeg on an m2 pro Mac and on my all-amd tower. I was happy to see that the amf api offers a lot of different rc modes. I followed this document to tweak the parameters. First goal in mind was best quality at low file size with better speed than software (I know you "can only have two") so I figured that qvbr seemed to be a good option. I tried different commands just to find out that the options are ignored and the file that comes out is always the exact same eg:

ffmpeg -t 60 -i Rainbow.mp4 -c:v hevc_amf -an blebb.mp4


ffmpeg -t 60 -i Rainbow.mp4 -c:v hevc_amf -rc hqvbr -an blabb.mp4


ffmpeg -t 60 -i Rainbow.mp4 -c:v hevc_amf -rc qvbr -an -qvbr_quality_level 19 blibb.mp4

Did I do something wrong? Do I need to install some drivers? I found this documentation but im not sure if it's about compiling ffmpeg or setting it up or if I need to use ffmpeg from the amd sdk... Im pretty sure that my commands are using accellerated encoding because it is more than two times faster than libx265 software encoding.
The card in my system is a Vega 64. My CPU is a Ryzen 7700X.
I don't really know where to even begin troubleshooting. If someone would give me a nudge in the right direction I would be really grateful.
